# Ping to server for external connectivity

Tags: c#, ping

I have a c# application that has a module for checks the server connection. The relevant code is like the following:

```
private void PingCheck(string hostName)
{
    using (var p = new Ping())
    {
        try
        {
            var pr = p.Send(hostName, 2000);

            if (pr.Status != IPStatus.Success)
            {
                log.ErrorFormat("Ping error! Host = {0},  Ping status = {1}", hostName, pr.Status.ToString());
            }
        }
        catch (Exception exc)
        {
            log.Error("Ping error!", exc);
        }
    }
}
```

We have deployed this application to our server that is inside the same network as the target machine. That's why this method checks internal connectivity. Is there any way to check server external connectivity? Because sometimes server connection is available in our network although connection from external network is down. How can I achieve this?

Comment: Did you try to use an external ip as hostname???

Comment: Pinging is rather straightforward, you only need to supply an IP (other parameters are optional, and generally don't change the fact that you only need an IP to ping it). So changing the IP to an external one should suffice to make this work as far as I'm aware.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, there is not, since you are on the server itself.

Either ping some resource outside to check connectivity, or use the [`NetworkInterface.GetIsNetworkAvailable()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.networkinformation.networkinterface.getisnetworkavailable.aspx) method to check whether there is an active connection.